# Simple mono audio phase inverter

Tags: audio, inverter, phase

I'm having some bass cancellation problems with my active subwoofer. It doesn't get along with my 2.0 system (different brands).

The subwoofer has a mono line input. I changed the polarity of the line cable going to the subwoofer and the bass came back to life. 
The downside is I get a 50 Hz hum when the subwoofer volume is maxed and no sound is playing. With the normal cable no hum is present.
As I searched more on the internet, I found that some subwoofers come from factory with a phase shifter switch. I don't have that and I'm looking to build one myself. From my POV the problem doesn't seem to be that complicated, but the schematics I found for phase inverters seem to contradict me. I would have preferred a passive one, but I guess that's utopic...

The subwoofer is new and and opening to switch the driver's cables will void my warranty.

Comment: Simply inverting the signal is trivial with an opamp, but may just move the cancellation to a different frequency. You probably need to find (or measure) the phase response (or group delay vs frequency) of both your main speakers and the sub (with its own crossover) and design a group delay equaliser to keep them in phase throughout the LF end of the spectrum.

Answer (score 2):

The subject is definitely quite complex, as different filtering and speaker design will introduce phase shifts and group delays, but in your case, if a simple 180º inversion seems to do the job, you can achieve that by simply opening the subwoofer box and swapping the leads on the speaker itself. A lot easier than building a line-level phase switch.